# Apple Pay iOS Swift Apply Coupon

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have In-app purchase in my application but now I want to apply the backend manageable coupon codes to be applied on the subscription.

For example if I apply a coupon code the amount should be reduced and effective amount should be less then current; Suppose a 10% coupon code on USD$1000, the price to USD$900.

The problem is amount is linked to the product and charged by Apple.

How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you apply the coupon before you submitted the payment request to ApplePay - i.e. You apply the coupon to get the new total of $900 and that is the amount you put in the PKPaymentRequest

Comment: That does not allow the custom payment, we can only pass the product identifiers : 

let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray[self.selectedProductIndex] as SKProduct) 
            
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

Comment: Ok, you are talking about IAP, not Apple Pay.  With IAP you cannot apply discounts using coupons.

Comment: You can offer [introductory pricing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/offering_introductory_pricing_in_your_app) for subscriptions

Comment: That will not work as There could be lot of coupon codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use coupon codes to decrease the price of an in-app purchase.

For auto renewing subscription IAPs you can offer [introductory pricing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/offering_introductory_pricing_in_your_app).

You could also use a coupon code to unlock visibility of a different in-app product in your app that is charged at a lower price, but if it is a subscription then that lower price would be charged ongoing.

Perhaps you could try combining the two; The coupon code makes a subscription with an introductory price available.  Without the coupon code the user only sees the subscription without the introductory price.

Comment: Are you sure regarding it?

Comment: Absolutely; the price is set in App Store Connect.  You cannot modify the price from within your app.

Comment: Is there anything in SKPayment option to customise the amount possibly?

Comment: No, the price is set in App Store Connect

Comment: Let me explore more, I guess apple cant left this as it is as coupons are required in now days. There must be any solution, isn't it?

Comment: I wouldn't expect Apple to change this any time soon. Allowing the price to be modified on the app side is a big security hole. An attacker can modify the app to send through a request for  the IAP at $0. By having the price set in App Store Connect this attack is eliminated. In recent years Apple have added free trials and introductory pricing to subscriptions. I can't see them adding coupon codes; they have potential for abuse. App creators could sell coupon codes outside the app that are then used to provide free or discounted IAPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two in app purchases in appstore connect
for example if your purchase is called fun pack
then you can have a purchase called fun pack in app store connect priced at 9.99 and have another fun pack priced for 7.99
so if your user uses a coupon then you should call the purchase method so that it purchases the 7.99$ iAP . if they purchase it without a coupon then just purchase the 9.99$ pack. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Coupon could be any kind of and any amount. I cant create lot of ..... This will not work